# Java import error when writing code in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm writing some code and I'm getting errors on four different lines saying that packages don't exist. The errors are on lines 7 to 10, which say `package org.web3d.x3d.sai does not exist`. The code that I have for this project is:

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(null);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Component browserComponent = (Component)  x3dComponent.getImplementation();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(browserComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[]   {"test.x3dv"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And the code for the test.x3dv is:

```
#X3D V3.0 utf8

PROFILE Interactive

DEF TS TimeSensor {
  cycleInterval 3
  loop TRUE
}

DEF TG Transform {
  rotation 0 1 0 0
  children Shape {
    geometry Box {}
    appearance Appearance {
      material DEF MAT Material {
        diffuseColor 1 0 0
      }
    }
  }
}

DEF OI OrientationInterpolator {
  key [ 0 0.5 1 ]
  keyValue [
     0 1 0 0
     0 1 0 3.14
     0 1 0 6.28
  ]
}

ROUTE TS.fraction_changed TO OI.set_fraction 
ROUTE OI.value_changed TO TG.rotation
```

The reason why I'm making this little project is because I need to display `.x3d` files through a Java project. I'm put `-Xmx450M -Djava.library.path='F:\Uni\Uni work\Year Three\xj3d-code-12559-trunk\bin'` in the project properties VM option and have put all the `x3d jars` in a library called `Xj3D`.

When I've written this code. I have the errors on lines 7 to 10 and I don't know why.

**EDIT**

I've looked through all the Xj3D code trunk file that I have that has got the `.jars` in but I don't think it has the `org.web3d.x3d.sai jar` in.

**EDIT 2**

I've downloaded the `org.web3d.x3d.sai` and I've put it in the JARS lib folder that I've made in Netbeans. But I'm still getting the errors.

**EDIT 3**

I've moved things round and I've only used that one jar. I've unzipped the file and used the jar itself and the errors have gone. However, a new problem has occurred while I run the piece of code and it's giving me a NotSupportedException.

Comment: you have those errors because: 'package org.web3d.x3d.sai does not exist'. do you have all the jars you need on your path?

Comment: Check whether the jars added to your build path.

Comment: All the jars that I have are all in the Xj3D library that I made and I can't seem to see the `org.web3d.x3d.sai` jar

Comment: did you add your library to your project, just saying that you could have forgotten.

Comment: I have added the library to the project and I'm still getting the errors

Comment: in the projects tab of netbeans , and under you project you will find library , expand it and you will find Xj3D library , expand it also you will find your jars there .Now check if the jar responsible for package org.web3d.x3d.sai is there

Comment: I've just looked through every single folder of the Xj3D code 12559 trunk folder to see if I can find the jar responsible for the package and I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Google -> org.web3d.x3d.sai -> [first link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxj3dsaijar.htm) -> find [download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/xj3d/xj3d-sai.jar.zip) -> Put it netbeans /lib folder -> Profit

Comment: I've downloaded it, and put it into my project but it's still giving the same errors

Comment: Did you unzip the file? It needs to be the jar itself, not the zip in the lib directory.

Comment: I did unzip the file and I'm using the jar itself